# How to chop off X number of characters across multiple records?

Tags: sql-server, string

Hello all!
I have a field that contains geographical locations in the city-state format:

1. Boston, MA
2. Los Angeles, CA
3. Helena, MT
4. ...

The field spans for some 230 records. My task is to chop off the four final characters in each record. How do I go about it? Any ideas?
Thank you!

Comment: Hey what is the final out you required based on the example you provided

Comment: Is the pattern always the same: <comma> + <space> + <2 chars>?

Comment: Are you chopping off or separating this value? City names can repeat across states...makes more sense if you are normalizing the data verses removing dependency columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DECLARE @tab TABLE(statename VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO @tab
(
      statename
)
select 'Boston, MA' UNION ALL
select 'Los Angeles, CA' UNION ALL
select 'Helena, MT' 


SELECT SUBSTRING(statename,0,LEN(statename)-3) FROM @tab t

SELECT LEFT(statename,LEN(statename)-4)FROM @tab t
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need all text until the last coma and maybe the pattern is not always the same:

```
<coma> + <space> + <2 characters>
```

You can reverse the string and get the position of the last `<coma>` in this way:

```
UPDATE t
SET location = SUBSTRING(location, 1, LEN(location) - CHARINDEX(',', REVERSE(location)));
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5558fd2b303e34d05062fd8612677c8d)*